# Lazyloading in iphone+Not able to display the downloaded image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, lazy-loading

I am implementing one sample code for lazy loading.
I am having one array whihc is having 10url of image:-
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    iconDownloader = [imageDownloadsInProgress objectForKey:indexPath];

    if (!iconDownloader.ImageDispaly)
    {
        if (Tble.dragging == NO && Tble.decelerating == NO)
        {
            [self startIconDownload:[ArrayImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forIndexPath:indexPath];
        }

        //cell.imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"event_image.png"];
        cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"default-image.png"];
        NSLog(@"image not download");
    }
    else
    {
        //cell.imgView.image=[aTweet objectForKey:@"image"];
        cell.imageView.image=iconDownloader.ImageDispaly.image;

    } 

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table cell image support
- (void)startIconDownload:(NSString *)str forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //[imageDownloadsInProgress retain];
    iconDownloader = [imageDownloadsInProgress objectForKey:indexPath];
    if (iconDownloader == nil) 
    {
        iconDownloader = [[IconDownloader alloc] init];
       // iconDownloader.appRecord = aTweet;
        iconDownloader.imageurlstring=[ArrayImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        iconDownloader.indexPathInTableView = indexPath;
        iconDownloader.delegate = self;
        [imageDownloadsInProgress setObject:iconDownloader forKey:indexPath];
        [iconDownloader startDownload];
        [imageDownloadsInProgress retain];
        [iconDownloader release];   
    }
}

// this method is used in case the user scrolled into a set of cells that don't have their app icons yet
- (void)loadImagesForOnscreenRows
{
    if ([ArrayImage count] > 0)
    {
        NSArray *visiblePaths = [Tble indexPathsForVisibleRows];
        for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in visiblePaths)
        {
            iconDownloader =[imageDownloadsInProgress objectForKey:indexPath];

            if (!iconDownloader.ImageDispaly) // avoid the app icon download if the app already has an icon
            {
                [self startIconDownload:[ArrayImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forIndexPath:indexPath];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)appImageDidLoad:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    iconDownloader =[imageDownloadsInProgress objectForKey:indexPath];
    if (iconDownloader != nil)
    {

        UIImageView *image=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,5,60,60)];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [Tble cellForRowAtIndexPath:iconDownloader.indexPathInTableView];
        // [cell.btnImage setBackgroundImage:[iconDownloader.appRecord valueForKey:@"image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        image.image=iconDownloader.ImageDispaly.image;
        cell.imageView.image=image.image;

        NSLog(@"%@ ======%@",cell.imageView.image,image.image);

    }

}
```

This is what i am getting on the console for
 NSLog(@"%@ ======%@",cell.imageView.image,image.image); 
while executing the application

```
2012-05-28 16:41:44.998 Lazyloading[97195:207] <UIImage: 0x4b56300> ======<UIImage: 0x4b56300>
2012-05-28 16:41:44.999 Lazyloading[97195:207] <UIImage: 0x4e24f00> ======<UIImage: 0x4e24f00>
2012-05-28 16:41:45.000 Lazyloading[97195:207] <UIImage: 0x4b55df0> ======<UIImage: 0x4b55df0>
2012-05-28 16:41:45.001 Lazyloading[97195:207] <UIImage: 0x4b406e0> ======<UIImage: 0x4b406e0>
2012-05-28 16:41:45.260 Lazyloading[97195:207] <UIImage: 0x4e2f9f0> ======<UIImage: 0x4e2f9f0>
2012-05-28 16:41:45.263 Lazyloading[97195:207] <UIImage: 0x4e0a2e0> ======<UIImage: 0x4e0a2e0>
2012-05-28 16:41:45.294 Lazyloading[97195:207] <UIImage: 0x4b40180> ======<UIImage: 0x4b40180>
```

But the images is not been displayed in tableview..
Can any body please help me out of this..

Comment: Have you not followed demo provided by apple properly on lazy loading refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) link properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling:

```
[cell setNeedsDisplay];
```

Where your NSLog line is:

```
NSLog(@"%@ ======%@",cell.imageView.image,image.image);
```

Comment: Odd... The code where you create an imageView and assign the image to it looks redundant, but not the problem.  Why not just have this:  `UITableViewCell *cell = [Tble cellForRowAtIndexPath:iconDownloader.indexPathInTableView]; cell.imageView.image = iconDownloader.ImageDispaly.image;`.  I'm assuming ImageDispaly is a typo but have kept it.  Have you checked the width/height and other information in the downloaded image to ensure it is correct.